# Xcode Validate vs Submit to App Store

Tags: ios, xcode

I've been pushing apps out to the App store for some time now but I've never really wrapped my head around what the difference between `Validate...` and `Submit to App Store...` was.  I always assumed the **Submite to App Store...** Task ran a validation on its own.

Am I wasting time by running a separate validate task

Answer (score 23):

Yes, submitting to the app store runs the validation as well. You should validate if you're not submitting to the app store, but exporting (ad-hoc, etc.).

Validation uploads the bundle to iTuneConnect, where some automated tests are run on it.

Comment: So, if one wants to distribute the app to the app store, you don't need to run validation.

Comment: If you are distributing your app, I think validation is a waste of time. I've found it doesn't catch some errors that the upload automated test finds and I end up having the binary "Uploaded with issues".

Answer (score 13):

Validate is just a automated test that will check quickly the packaging of your application (icon, provisionning profile,…)

The package is **not pushed** to Apple validating team.

Answer (score 1):

Validate is to be used during development when the code is not final.

You only use the Submit to AppStore once the app is finished.

In my experience though, validate didn't caught some problem, that were reporting by AppStore check.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Nicolas's answer - validate is very useful for Ad-Hoc distribution, not bound for the store.